# How to convert a slice of derived type to slice of base type?

Tags: go, types

Say we have a base type and from it we derive another type

```
type baseType struct {
}

type derivedType struct {
   baseType
}
```

How do I convert a slice of derivedType into baseType?

```
derivedTypeSlice := []derivedType{}

func iTakeBaseSlice(baseSlice []baseType ) {
}

iTakeBaseSlice(???derivedTypeSlice)
```

---

@Gavin suggested to use generics

```
func iTakeBaseSlice[T baseType | derivedType](baseSlice []T) {
}
```

Only con with this approach is that the function has to know all of the derived types that will call it. Which while not a problem for unexported function(most likely unexported function will know types that are calling it within the package) is a problem for exported functions.

---

My idea is to loop over derived slice and append into new slice of base type

```
derivedTypeSlice := []derivedType{}
baseTypeSlice := []baseTypeSlice{}
for _, derivedTypeElement := range derivedTGypeSlice {
   baseTypeSlice = append(baseTypeSlice, derivedTypeElement.baseType)
}
iTakeBaseSlice(baseTypeSlice)
```

Con of this approach is the performance and memory penalties. As derived slice will be duplicated into base slice, therefore doubling memory usage. Append operation(which could be avoided if derived slice is const size) is costly performance wise.

Comment: I'd start by avoiding dynamic memory allocation in the `append` by creating `baseTypeSlice` with the required capacity up-front. Assuming you do this, have you measured and confirmed that memory allocation is a problem?

Comment: You can use generics e.g. `func iTakeBaseSlice[T baseType | derivedType](slice []T) { ... }`: https://go.dev/play/p/QlWYfzICTbs. This has the downfall that you have to explicitly list all the compatible types in the signature.

Comment: @ChrisDrew that would require that size of derived type slice is also a constant and you would still have to allocate base type slice size in any stack that is needing this conversion. You right in thinking that you get rid of slice resizing which does help a lot performance wise.

Comment: @Gavin I like your solution a lot. Thank you for the idea

Comment: There are no type casts in Go so you cannot do type cast these types. The rules for type _conversions_ are pretty simple and explained in the language spec. Redesign.

Comment: @Volker I'm looking for a nice way to call a function that only needs to do something with baseType. If there isn't a straightforward way to go from derived slice to base slice using what I call casting, then a nice way to get there is still appreciated.

Comment: This is actually addressed by [this entry in the official FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#convert_slice_with_same_underlying_type).

Answer (score 4):

struct embedding is not subclassing.  In general, `[]baseType` and `[]derivedType` are not assignable.

One way you can handle this is to use interfaces.  With an array of interfaces, each value could have its own type.  You can write the function that accepts the interface, and use methods to interact with the items (or reflection).  So then your list type could be `[]interface{...}` (where `...` is the methods you need)

An interface is two pointers: a type pointer and a pointer to the value.  You can also consider whether to use just the value pointer.  In that way, you would create a list of pointers to the "base type" and pass that to your function that wants to take the base type.  So then it would be `[]*baseType`.

Depending on the size of the list, creating a new list and populating it might be faster than you think.  Benchmark it and find out!